# Identify the bash exit code from a command run in a sub shell - when set -e is used

Tags: bash

Obviously **$?** could be used, but the script contains set -e, which causes an exit as soon as a command fails

A very artifical example:

```
set -eu -o pipefail
...
# file does_not_exist does not exist
# the following would result in an immediate exit of the script
mv does_not_exist new_file
# as does the following
$(mv does_not_exist new_file)
# but this neat trick doesn't exit the script
declare -r RES=$(mv does_not_exist new_file)
# however I'd also like to get at the exit code of **mv**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can examine `$?` in the "or" part of the command:

```
set -e
ls /does-not-exist || echo $?
echo end
```

The behaviour is documented in `man bash` under `set`:

> The shell does not exit if  the  command
>                         that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or
>                         `until` keyword, part of the test  following  the `if` or  `elif` reserved
>                         words,  part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a  pipeline  but  the
>                         last,  or if the command's return value is being inverted with `!`.

Comment: Apologies, I neglected to add the full set command, which I've now added to the original Q

set -eu -o pipefail

Comment: declare -r RES=$(mv does_not_exist new_file || echo $?)

Comment: @MaxSmith: Added the relevant part of the documentation